# Using function regul.plot in pastecs to plot regularized time series

Tags: r, time-series

I need to upgrade an R code using the library `pastecs` to regularize some time series. Unfortunately the docs I found are terrible and among many things I don't understand the plots I get from the function `plot.regul`.

For instance, if x and y are vectors (dates and values resp.), the following code:

```
library(pastecs)

temp <- as.data.frame(x)
temp["numb_sec"] <- NA
temp["numb_sec"] <- (temp[,1]-min(temp[,1]))
regulstep <- 7*24*3600
test<-regul(as.numeric(temp[,"numsec"]),y=as.numeric(y),
            deltat=regulstep,units="sec")
plot.regul(test)
```

gives:

[image]

what does it mean ?

My guess: the red plot would be the regularized time serie overplotted on the original curve in black. The red curve would have 781 points like the original curve, because I didn't set the `n` parameter. The 781 points would be separated by a 7*24*3600 sec gap which make ~4.7e8 sec, that's why the right-hand part of the plot is black only.

Questions about the guess: Is it right ? Is there a good doc or anything where I can find this information without guessing ?

More questions: Why are some points encircled ? Why the dotted lines ?

---

upgrade: I also guess encircled points are those where regularization implies a time that already exists in the original curve